# Twilio Error SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I am forwarding SMS using studio flow and I want to use Message from Setting to use `{{trigger.message.From}}` rather than `{{flow.channel.address}}`

And it gives me this error
`The From phone number +1xxxxxxxxxx is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account`

The reason for using this setting is when SMS is forwarded to the number it's sent from the Twilio number but I want it to send from the original number

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

With Twilio, you can only send SMS messages from SMS capable phone numbers that you have bought, ported into or hosted in your account.

You cannot use the From number of an incoming message as the From number of an outbound message.

Comment: what about Alpha numeric Sender ID.? Since they are not registrable how do we manage this error?

Comment: Alphanumeric sender IDs are registrable in some countries (mandatory in some), check [the sms guidelines for the country your are sending to](https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/sms). Those guidelines will also tell you whether alphanumeric sender IDs are supported in the country. One last thing, you need to have an upgraded account to send with an alphanumeric ID.